# Cross Domain jQuery Ajax Using C# and WFC

Tags: c#, web-services, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a small webservice written in C# and WCF.

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        return "Hello Worlds";
    }
}
```

I have a little jQuery code;

```
        $.support.cors = true;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:61614/Service1.asmx/HelloWorld",
            data: '{}',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                alert(0);
            }, error: function (a, b, c) { alert("Err:" + c ); 
            }
        });
```

This calls the webservice. There are no problems making the call, but it errors out on the return.

The webservice is in one application, and the Web page is simply an HTML page on it's own.  Eventually, the HTML will be used within PhoneGap.

I have tried all sorts of things.

Adding in `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` causes the whole call to fail.
Using `dataType: 'jsonp"` causes call to fail.

Basically, the above calls the WS but errors out on return which is weird.

My requirement is that I need to return a JSON object from the webservice, and it has to work in Safari.

Does anyone have complete sample code of a JSONP call?

Comment: not sure if it helps http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/186235/Making-a-JSONP-Call-to-a-WCF-Data-Service-using-da

Comment: @griegs - First step, make sure http://localhost:61614/Service1.asmx/HelloWorld?callback=test returns a JavaScript function in your browser that looks like this: `test({'say':'HelloWorld'});`. Until you do that, the jsonp request will not be successful. You can test this in the address bar. Hope this helps.

Comment: One thing to clarify. Are you 100% sure you're making requests across domains once you go live? If it's the same domain, then you can just return the JSON without the padding/wrapper function.

Answer (score 0):

From [jQuery getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/):

> If the URL includes the string "callback=?" (or similar, as defined by the server-side API), the request is treated as JSONP instead. See the discussion of the jsonp data type in $.ajax() for more details.

In order for your request to be treated as a JSONP request, you need to include `callback=?` in your URL. This tells jQuery to create a callback function and pass the name of that function as the callback parameter to your server.

In the server-side code, your method must then return JSON code wrapped, or padded, with the name of the JavaScript function passed in as the callback parameter in the query string.

Essentially, what you're doing is returning JavaScript to the client browser, which runs immediately, and invokes a function already defined in the context of the page.

JavaScript:

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost:61614/Service1.asmx/HelloWorld?callback=?",
    function(data) {

        // alert raw JSON data
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));

        // access the "say" property and alert it
        alert(data.say);
    }
);
```

Server-Side:

This is a crude version of what you'd need to do on the server-side:

```
// get the callback parameter value and assign to the String callback
...
return callback + "( { 'say' : 'HelloWorld' } );";
```

**Further technical explanation of what is happening under the hood:**

While this is not something you need to know today, this may help you understand more about how jQuery is implementing JSONP.

This evaluates to something that might look like this:

```
return "jquery43214321432143242({'say':'HelloWorld'});"
```

where `jquery43214321432143242` is the random name given for your success callback function. Again, since the returned text is returned using text/javascript, it runs immediately, passing the `{'say':'HelloWorld'}` object in as a parameter to the function.

The resulting output should be an alert message representing the raw JSON, and the words "HelloWorld", pulled from the `.say` property.

Comment: jmort253, this still isn't calling the web service for some reason.

Comment: Does http://localhost:61614/Service1.asmx/HelloWorld?callback=test return `test({'say':'HelloWorld'});` in your browser? If not, that's the first step. It is basically dynamically generated text/javascript. Please try that first.

Comment: Here is a more complicated JSONP example, but it should give you an idea of what you'd need to see when hitting your URL in your browser. Note how the JSON object is wrapped in the function called "test":  http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=blue%20angels&rpp=5&include_entities=true&result_type=mixed&callback=test

Comment: this is what i am returning return "({'data' : 'Hello Worlds'} )";

Comment: But it's not even getting to the web service irrespective of what it returns, the breakpoint is never triggered

Comment: These are apparent quirks with .NET and JSON requests. See this article. I'll also update my answer to reflect the workaround. However, it's really important to know whether or not you need cross-domain JSONP (I am making a request from example.com to a server at domain.com) or just regular JSON (I am making the request from a page on example.com to a server at example.com on the same domain.)  http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10944/discussion-between-jmort253-and-griegs)

Comment: I will be going from an iPhone to my domain.  So i'm a little unsure whether that qualifies as x-domain

Comment: Is it from a browser on the iPhone or a native app. If it's a native app, then plain JSON should work, as you won't be making the request from a browser.

Comment: I have made this answer "Community Wiki". Anyone can edit it. I am over my head on this one, as C# apparently requires some different techniques when working with JSON. Still, I feel this content has some value, so rather than deleting it, it is here for anyone to edit and improve.